# Sublime Text 3 - jQuery highlighted error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, sublimetext3

I am teaching myself jQuery for flexibility in the work SharePoint environment. I have added this file to the proper destination within SharePoint (and everything seems to be working), but I am still showing some weird highlighting in Sublime Text 3.

Attached is an image of the code in ST3: 
[image: jQuery Syntax Error?]

Is my syntax correct on source #2? I really do not want to miss anything, though this is quite a small amount of code (forgive me for syntax within the post as I am still getting the hang of it)

```js
<script src = "https://mysite/teams/spe/Style%20Library/tts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 

<script src = "https://mysite/teams/spe/Style%20Library/tts/sputility.js" > < /script>

  
  <script>
  // wait for the window to load
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Get a single select dropdown field
    var ticketType = SPUtility.GetSPField('Ticket Type');

    // create a function to show or hide Priority based on Project's value
    var showOrHideField = function() {
      var ticketTypeValue = ticketType.GetValue();
      // Hide the Priority field if the selected
    }
    value is Project
    if (ticketTypeValue === 'Project') {
      SPUtility.HideSPField('Priority');
    } else {
      SPUtility.ShowSPField('Priority');
    };

    // run at startup (for edit form)
    showOrHideField();

    // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
    $(ticketType.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);

    //hide Category field from NewForm
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Category')

    //hide issue status field from NewForm
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Issue Status')

    //hide comments field from NewForm
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Comments')
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the pink syntax highlighting, your script URLs in `line 1` and `line 2` has a literal space and since URLs can't have literal spaces, it is converted to its ASCII code i.e. `%20`.

Just replace the `%20` with `+` and it should remove the syntax error highlighting.

> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
>   to be converted into a valid ASCII format. URL encoding replaces
>   unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
>   URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space
>   with a plus (+) sign or with %20.
>
> Via - [URL Encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

---

If you have access to the website's files and folders, I would recommend checking if the folder `Style%20Library` has a folder name of `Style Library` or not and if that is the case, rename it to `StyleLibrary` and remove the %20 from your script urls.

### UPDATE:

And assuming you're talking about the **script** tags syntax color highlighting, well if you change the syntax highlight settings for **Sublime Text 3** to HTML, the weird highlight disappears.

It will obviously look weird in js because a js file shouldn't have `<script</script>` tags nor the script links in line 1 and line 2 in the first place and you should remove them from your js file.

---

**tldr:** Change the syntax highlight settings to HTML in **View > Syntax > HTML** if this is an html file ior remove the script tags and script links if this is a JS file. Also, avoid literal spaces in folder names and use camelCase writing if you really have to have word distinctions in folder names.

Comment: The highlighting problem seems to start with the first `</script>`. Notice that the `>` is not red.

Comment: Why is it highlighting `%20Library` in the second URL, but not the first one?

Comment: @Barmar Answer updated. And regarding the `%20`, I think that since Sublime's syntax detects this file as a js file (I presume), the highlight thinks the link is a string or something because its wrapped in quotes but what I mentioned above regarding changing %20 to + or removing the literal space altogether is good practice in writing url links or folder names regardless. If the distinction is that necessary between words in the url, then camelCase writing should be used.

Comment: tldr added to the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid javascript as well, looks like you were going for this

```
var showOrHideField = function() {
  var ticketTypeValue = ticketType.GetValue();
  // Hide the Priority field if the selected value is Project
  if (ticketTypeValue === 'Project') {
      SPUtility.HideSPField('Priority');
  } else {
      SPUtility.ShowSPField('Priority');
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is a true, I don't think it's what he's asking about